# Unity quaternion, leaving the x and z rotations as they are

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

So to start off: Here's my code:
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class LockRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
public Transform Yrotation;
public float Rotationthingy;
public Quaternion Qrotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

void Start()
{
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Rotationthingy = Yrotation.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

    Qrotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Rotationthingy, 0);
    m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(Qrotation);

}
}
```

Okay, so this is my code. the Yrotation is the rotation of another object which I want to "copy". If you need any more details, just ask. And the thing I want to achive is to leave the x and z in Qrotation unspecified.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid now xD. I should have thought of that myself.

Comment: It's alright, there's lots of things in Unity that I forget all the time. I've posted as an answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
Qrotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, Rotationthingy, transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

instead of just putting zeroes for `X` and `Z`